# Inconsistent behaviour with Javascript Date getTime() function

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I am trying to make a filter based on hours for timestamps (in this example filter for all times after 8 am):

```
    var beginningTimeValue = new Date('2020-01-01 08:00:00');
    var unique = [["value","value","value","value","12/01/2021 00:03:35","value"],["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 00:03:35","value"], ["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 08:03:35","value"], ["value","value","value","value","01/01/2020 13:03:35","value"]]
      
    if(!beginningTimeValue == ""){
      unique = unique.filter(function(row)
                             {
        var rYear = row[4].substring(6, 10);
        var rMonth = row[4].substring(3, 5);
        var rDay = row[4].substring(0, 2);
        var rHour = row[4].substring(11, 13);
        var rMinute = row[4].substring(14, 16);
        var rSecond = row[4].substring(17, 19);
        var bTime = new Date(parseInt(rYear, 10), parseInt(rMonth, 10), parseInt(rDay, 10), parseInt(rHour, 10), parseInt(rMinute, 10), parseInt(rSecond, 10));
        console.log("ODATE = " + rYear + "/" + rMonth + "/" + rDay + "_" + rHour + ":" + rMinute + ":" + rSecond);
        console.log("BDATE = " + bTime.getFullYear() + "/" + bTime.getMonth() + "/" + bTime.getDate() + "_" + bTime.getHours() + ":" + bTime.getMinutes() + ":" + bTime.getSeconds());
        beginningTimeValue.setYear(bTime.getYear());
        beginningTimeValue.setMonth(bTime.getMonth());
        beginningTimeValue.setDate(bTime.getDate());
        if(bTime.getTime() >= beginningTimeValue.getTime()){
            console.log(bTime.getTime()*24*3600*1000 + " VS " + beginningTimeValue.getTime()*24*3600*1000);
        }
        else{
          console.log("FALSE");
        }
        return bTime.getTime() >= beginningTimeValue.getTime();
      }
                            );
    }
    console.log(unique);
```

I have debugged my way to finding out that I wouldn't get a `FALSE` value in the 2nd `IF`, however I am at a loss as to why the `.getTime()` function returns vastly different values for my console log:

> "136556220816000000000 VS -5.0438323821312e+21"

> "136560264336000000000 VS -5.0438323821312e+21"

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I've modified the question to get rid of the overflow problem. However the question still remains as to why the date comparison is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
beginningTimeValue.setYear(bTime.getYear());
```

The (deprecated) [`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) function returns

> [a] number representing the year of the given date, according to local
> time, minus 1900.

The (also deprecated) [`setYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear) function

> [...] interprets any two-digit number as an offset to `1900`

In your case, `getYear()` returns a value like `121`, which is *not* a two-digit number. When you subsequently invoke `setYear()` with that value, you get a date that is set to the year 121 instead of 2021.

Since `getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since 1970, and 121 is before 1970, you get a negative number.

---

**TL;DR:** use [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) and [`setFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) instead of `getYear()` and `setYear()`.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I feel like I've scoured my code so many times for a mistake, it's great to have a fresh pair of eyes!